# iPhone NSString overwrite sensitive data with zeros

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

My app temporarily stores a lot of sensitive data and I want to overwrite the data in memory again.

I found a post earlier suggesting this:

```
char* block = malloc(200);
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:length:encoding:freeWhenDone];
//use string
memset(block, 0, 200);// overwrite block with 0
[string release];
free(block);
```

but this does not work for me. Because I collect the data in many different ways. For example:

```
mySensibleString = [anotherString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5,15)];
```

or even get it through a HTTPS connection:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
```

So I am wondering whether there is any way to locate the sensitive data stored within the object in memory and find out its length and overwrite that memory (no matter how complicated)?

Comment: Do you mean 'sensitive'?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help. Corrected the post.

Comment: If the sensitive data can be read from the memory, then what is safe? Seems kinda useless, just release the string when you're done..

Comment: Note that iOS doesn't page memory out to disk, so in order for someone to be able to read the content of your app's memory, they would have to be able to get it directly from RAM.  It's not like a desktop OS, where RAM is often paged out to the hard disk, making it possible to read as a file.  An attacker would either have to have compromised the OS to allow it to read memory from another running process, or they would need to have physical access to the device and attach it to a machine capable of reading the content of the RAM.  I'm not even sure the latter is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's far too many unknowns to make such an endeavour worth it. You don't know the route data has taken before it got to you, and where copies have been left in memory but not scrubbed, etc.

If you followed any of the news about iPhone security in the last year, you'll see it's a got a pretty bad rep at the minute -- pretty flawed encryption, bad things happening like keyboard data possibly being retained for a long long time, etc. I wouldn't bother if I was you!

Obviously, what data is written to disk is another matter and worth considering.

Bottom line: really, REALLY sensitive important data probably just shouldn't go anywhere near an iPhone (and maybe some other smart devices to boot).

Answer (score 1):

What if you were to encrypt any data that is stored on the heap? So anytime you are storing something to a variable or a data structure pass it through a cipher. And then anytime you want to use it just decrypt it.

Saves you the trouble of trying to wipe anything. Even if they can get to the data, if they don't know your encryption phrase/key/method then they can't read it.